# Edit max_conns in Kubernetes ingress Ngnix?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-reverse-proxy, kubernetes-ingress

Im trying to limit the number of concurrent connection to servers in my Nginx ingress.

is max_conns supported in Ngnix ingress? how can i edit or add it?

> max_conns=number
>   limits the maximum number of simultaneous active connections to the proxied server (1.11.5). Default value is zero, meaning there is no limit. If the server group does not reside in the shared memory, the limitation works per each worker process.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#upstream

exmple of an Nginx conf using max_conn

```
upstream backend {
server backend1.example.com  max_conns=3;
server backend2.example.com;}
```

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, what needed to be done in order to add max_conns (or any other parameter that is not supported by the ingress configmap) - is to change the template.

changing the template /etc/nginx/template/nginx.tmpl like this:

```
upstream {{ $upstream.Name }} {
    # Load balance algorithm; empty for round robin, which is the default
    {{ if ne $cfg.LoadBalanceAlgorithm "round_robin" }}
    {{ $cfg.LoadBalanceAlgorithm }};
    {{ end }}

    {{ if $upstream.UpstreamHashBy }}
    hash {{ $upstream.UpstreamHashBy }} consistent;
    {{ end }}

    {{ if (gt $cfg.UpstreamKeepaliveConnections 0) }}
    keepalive {{ $cfg.UpstreamKeepaliveConnections }};
    {{ end }}

    {{ range $server := $upstream.Endpoints }}server {{ $server.Address | formatIP }}:{{ $server.Port }} max_fails={{ $server.MaxFails }} fail_timeout={{ $server.FailTimeout }} max_conns=1;
    {{ end }}
}
```

(you can get the full file from the pod nginx-ingress-controller, just run bash on the pod and cat it)
will do the trick.
now create a configmap with the local nginx.tmpl:

```
kubectl create configmap nginx-template --from-file=nginx.tmpl=/localpath/nginx.tmpl
```

and then mount a volume to the deployment with this yaml:

```
        volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /etc/nginx/template
        name: nginx-template-volume
        readOnly: true
  volumes:
    - name: nginx-template-volume
      configMap:
        name: nginx-template
        items:
        - key: nginx.tmpl
          path: nginx.tmpl
```

- i needed to restart my NGINX ingress manually but i edited the ReplicationController because i didn't have a deployment (i guess its because im on minikube)

Comment: ingress-nginx-controller:v0.48.1:  `upstream upstream_balancer { # We no longer create "upstream" section for every backend`

Comment: `# Backends are handled dynamically using Lua.` no workaround for me now ,using v0.48.1.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#rate-limiting, there are annotations for limiting the number of connections:

> The annotations nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-connections,
> nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rps, and
> nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rpm define a limit on the
> connections that can be opened by a single client IP address. This can
> be used to mitigate DDoS Attacks.
>
> nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-connections: number of concurrent
> connections allowed from a single IP address.
>
> nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rps: number of connections that may
> be accepted from a given IP each second.
>
> nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/limit-rpm: number of connections that may
> be accepted from a given IP each minute.

You would need to add these annotations in your Ingress rule.

Comment: sorry, thats not what i need. i specifically need the parameter max_conn. "limits the maximum number of simultaneous active connections to the proxied server". The parameters you supplied are IP specific.