# How to set max_conn for nginx ingress?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller

I have Nginx Ingress Controller which is deployed via official Helm chart, in the doc I saw that I can set `max_conn` parameter, but I didn't get how to set it. I want to set it to 2, so that maximum of 2 clients could connect to my services. How do I set it? Should I set it in ingress controller values during `helm install` of Ingress Controller or in Ingress manifest?

Answer (score 0):

From this [document](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/advanced-configuration-with-annotations/#backend-services-upstreams) you can add these in the annotations

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: web-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    
    nginx.org/max-conns: 2
```

Try this and let me know if this works

Found a similar [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48659392/edit-max-conns-in-kubernetes-ingress-ngnix/48693860#48693860) with a different approach which can help you to resolve your issues.